# Undetected wireless

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

I have Ubuntu Mate 15.10 on a USB flash drive. I booted into it and looked to connect to my wifi and it was not listed in my networking connections. I looked in network connections in the system menu and it doesn't have any wireless adapters listed. Only the ethernet.

I've run lsusb and my wireless adapter is listed there. I just don't know where to go from here in getting it running. Learning this as I go.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT 1** - Here is the output from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0  
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:5406 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Micro U3  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

**EDIT 2** - Output from `usb-devices | awk '/8171/' RS=` and output from `iwconfig`

```
ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ usb-devices | awk '/8171/' RS=  
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0  
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1  
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=8171 Rev=02.00  
S:  Manufacturer=Manufacturer Realtek   
S:  Product=RTL8188S WLAN Adapter   
S:  SerialNumber=  
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA  
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=r8712u
```

=====

```
ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ iwconfig  
                      unassociated  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"  
          Mode:Auto  Access Point: Not-Associated   Sensitivity:0/0    
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off  
          Power Management:off  
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0  
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0  

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.  

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: Please add output of `usb-devices | awk '/8171/' RS=` and `iwconfig`.

Comment: Requested information added.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a driver this way. I tested that it does build. Run

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/chunkeey/rtl8192su.git
cd rtl8192su
make
sudo make load
```

But you will need to re-install it after kernel updates.